# How GridSearchCV in sklearn choose the cross-validation sets?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

```
svc = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid,scoring='f1_macro', verbose=1000)
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = svc.predict(X_test)
```

I run this code many times but the results are the same.
Does GridSearchCV choose the same cross-validation sets(not randomly choose)?

Answer (score 5):

`GridSearchCV` uses the `KFold` cross-validator per default and `KFold` doesn't shuffle the data per default. To enable shuffling, you would have to do

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

cross_validator = KFold(shuffle=True)
svc = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid, scoring='f1_macro', 
                   verbose=1000, cv=cross_validator)
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = svc.predict(X_test)
```